# Error in calculating age in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate age with the SQL statement below

```
round(datediff(now() - dateofbirth / 365))
```

gives the following error,

> 1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'

Comment: what type is dateofbirth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem :** `datediff` expects two parameters like `DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)` , as per the given question, there is only one parameter hence error.

**Solution :**  you have to use,

```
round(datediff(now() , (dateofbirth / 365)))
                     ^
```

the `datediff` returns `expression1 – expression2`, so you dont have to do it by yourself :) also **make sure the parameters are date or date-and-time expressions**

**EDIT :** Another error pointed out by @Jonathan Leffler,division is needed after the call to `DATEDIFF`.

```
round(datediff(now(),dateofbirth)/365)
```

Comment: Is the division needed after the call to DATEDIFF?

Comment: select round((datediff(now(), (dateofbirth)))/365) from member

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oopss! got it! :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

To view Today matches for example use this

```
SELECT `match_id`, `match_date` FROM `matches`
WHERE DATEDIFF ( CURDATE(),`match_date`) =0
```

Yesterday matches

```
SELECT `match_id`, `match_date` FROM `matches`
WHERE DATEDIFF ( CURDATE(),`match_date`) =1
```

Tommorow matches

```
SELECT `match_id`, `match_date` FROM `matches`
WHERE DATEDIFF ( CURDATE(),`match_date`) =0
```