# DateDiff SQL Error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, datediff

I have a problem with my SQL syntax. But I can not determine what is wrong with the syntax.
The syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM Inmuebles WHERE DATEDIFF(day, FechaIngreso, getdate()) <= 30
```

The reason why I put three parameters in the DATEDIFF function is because that I have read on here: [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

The execution of this query has returned the following error:

#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Then Google the mistake, and I came across the following post:

[Error in calculating age in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633243/error-in-calculating-age-in-mysql)

Having read this post, I decided to leave the query in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM Inmuebles WHERE DATEDIFF(FechaIngreso, getdate()) <= 30
```

But unfortunately tripped me with this error:

#1547 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted

Thanks for taking the time to read, please I hope you can forgive my horrible way to write English and can help with this problem.
Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using MS SQL Server syntax:

`GETDATE()` = MS SQL Server

`NOW()`/`CURDATE()` = MySQL

If you want to `DELETE` the records returned from your query above it should just be:

```
DELETE FROM Inmuebles 
WHERE DATEDIFF(FechaIngreso, NOW()) <= 30;
```

Comment: Great, you've found the answer, thank you very much, how would the syntax if I wanted to remove from the table the records of the result?
Again, thank you!